# Cannot use 'import.meta' outside a module in angular mfe?

Tags: angular

im using mfe(module federation microfrontend) in angular and im facing an error "import.meta outside a module"
my angular version is 14

please share an example for better understanding

[image]

// config file

,`name: "mfeProfile", filename: "remoteEntry.js", exposes: { './Module': './projects/project-name/src/app/profile/profile.module.ts'}`

Comment: Post something for the people on SO to go on to be able to help you, like the code where you are having an issue, and maybe you will get an answer. And, I am not making fun of you. I am just pointing out the fact that your post is awful, and in no way deserves the upvotes it got (probably from your sock puppet accounts).

Comment: thanks bro, may be this pic will help for understanding.